# How do I show "Delete From Library Only - Delete From Library And My Computer" dialog box in Windows Media Player 12

Tags: windows, windows-media-player

How can I show the "Delete From Library Only - Delete From Library And My Computer" dialog box in Windows Media Player 12? I checked "Don't show this message again" and it has vanished forever.

I couldn't find it in the *Options* menu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Tools » Options » Library* and it will have a box *Delete files from computer when deleted from library*.

You can check or uncheck this. It's the third one down.